# ¿Qué significan los símbolos antes del número de versión en el package.json?

Tags: nodejs

Usando `node.js`, en el `package.json` se puede ver en las dependencias el nombre y el número de versión, algo así:

```
"dependencies": {    
  "jshint": "^2.8.0"
}
```

Nótese que aparece el símbolo `^` (no sé el nombre en español pero al parecer en inglés se llama [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret)).

Sin embargo, en otros repositorios aparecen las dependencias con otro símbolo, así:

```
"dependencies": {    
  "jshint": "~1.8.0"
}
```

Nótese que ahora el símbolo que precede al número de versión es `~` (en inglés le llaman [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) y en español [virgulilla](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgulilla)).

También he visto repositorios con dependencias sin ninguno de los dos símbolos, algo así:

```
"dependencies": {    
  "jshint": "1.8.0"
}
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia de estos símbolos y qué significan en el `package.json`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para : `~` 1.8.0 coincidira con todas las `1.8.x` versiones, pero se perdera `1.9.0` (Este ha sido el comportamiento predeterminado).

Para: `^` se le actualizara a la ultima gran version (el primer número). `^ 2.8.0` coincidira con cualquier `2.x.x` de liberación incluyendo `2.9.0`,pero manteniendo la distancia de la version `3.0.0`

**Ejemplo** sobre 3.9.2: 
(sacado del link proporcionado al final)

```
Symbol     Dependency   Versions    Changes
tilde (~)   ~3.9.2        3.9.*      -bug fix

caret (^)   ^3.9.2        3.*.*      -backwards compatible new functionality 
                                     -old functionality deprecated, but operational
                                     -large internal refactor
                                     -bug fix
```

Semántica de versiones (Semantic Versioning) utiliza el número de la versión de tres partes.

```
  2           8           0
major       minor       patch
```

Para mas detalles puede consultar http://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/ (link ingles)

**Update:**
Cuando lei la pregunta no estaba o no vi que se preguntara sobre "1.8.0"

como dice @César Bustíos en su respuesta que acabo de leer version "Exactamente esta versión"

Para: `"1.8.0"` Exactamente esta version.

**Update:** `^` Caret, en español podria nombrarse como `acento circunflejo`, es el codigo 94 de ASCII code, que corresponde con el mismo codigo para caret.

(link 1) http://www.elcodigoascii.com.ar/codigos-ascii/intercalacion-acento-circunflejo-codigo-ascii-94.html

(link 2) https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acento_circunflejo

Answer (score 1):

Significan lo siguiente:

> version "Exactamente esta versión"
>
> ~version "Aproximadamente equivalente a la versión"
>
> ^version "Compatible con la versión"

Tomado de [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies). También, como recomiendan en la página, puedes echar un vistazo a la herramienta [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver), seguro con los ejemplos y las validaciones te queda mas claro.